# [], I am getting this as a json response

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to accept a json in succes function ie data here, I am getting data as [] but I am not getting **no data** in alert box. Is there something I am missing, can anyone help. Thanks in advance

```
    success: function (data) {
        $('#loader').hide();
        if (data != null) {
            alert('congratulations');
        }else{ 
            alert('no data');
        }
     }
```

Comment: first just `alert(data)` to see what it contains

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try replacing `if (data != null)` with `if ((data || []).length)`

Answer (score 0):

If you expect your data as array, then to test that it's not empty check its length:

```
if (data && data.length > 0) {
    // ...
}
```

because empty array `[]` is not `null`.

Answer (score 0):

When writing condition, these values are considered as false: '', 0, [], undefined, null

```
success: function (data) {
    $('#loader').hide();
    if (data == true)
        alert('congratulations');
    else
        alert('no data');
 }
```